# Python - object created outside of function is fully accessable inside?

Tags: python

i have some problems understanding the variable scope. For normal variables i understand it, but if i define a object things confuses me. Please have a look at this code:

```
class test():
    pass

text="hi there"
num=1

p=test()
p.var="good bye"
p.arr = []
p.num = 5

def output_before():
    print "before change: object text " ,p.var
    print "before change: object number ", p.num
    print "before change: basic text " ,text
    print "before change: basic num ", num

def output_after():
    print "after change: object text " ,p.var
    print "after change: object number ", p.num
    print "after change: basic text " ,text
    print "after change: basic num ", num



def change():
    text = "whats up"
    num=5
    p.num=10
    p.var="good night"
    p.arr.append ("sleep well")


output_before()
change()
output_after()

print p.arr

for i in range(5):
    change()
print p.arr
```

Which gives me this ouput:

```
before change: object text  good bye
before change: object number  5
before change: basic text  hi there
before change: basic num  1
after change: object text  good night
after change: object number  10
after change: basic text  hi there
after change: basic num  1
['sleep well']
['sleep well', 'sleep well', 'sleep well', 'sleep well', 'sleep well', 'sleep well']
```

The object from class test seems to be global by default. Is this right ?

Thanks,
Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how closures work. When you define function `output_after` it takes variable `text="hi there"` in the variable scope of this function. And this variable can be changed only inside the function.

But if you want to have global variables you need to use `global` construction:

```
def output_after():
   global text, num
   print "after change: object text " ,p.var
   print "after change: object number ", p.num
   print "after change: basic text " ,text
   print "after change: basic num ", num
```

As we know, all variable names in Python are said to be references to the values. So when we define function `output_after` we copy all current context (references to text, num, p objects). You can check the reference to object with `id` function.
When you change a value for text and num references will be changed, but for the object p will be the same.

Please, check this:

```
def change():
    print(id(text))
    text = "whats up"
    print(id(text))
    print(id(num))
    num=5
    print(id(text))
    print(id(p))
    p.num=10
    print(id(p))
```

You can see that references changed for num and text.

Comment: Thanks for your help. My goal is to understand the scopes here. I declared both the object p and the variables text and num outside. Why my object p is accessed without the global keyword, but the variables have to have it ?

Comment: Because p is a mutable object and text and num is immutable.

Comment: @xsanders I added more description.

Comment: @OleksandrYarushevskyi Why would text and num be immutable?

Comment: @RohithS98 implementation of CPython

Answer (score 1):

**Short answer**:
Any variable that is declared outside of the function or in the global scope (means the variable is not inside any kind of scopes e.g. class, methods, conditional statements,..., etc.) is known as global.

**Long debugged answer**:

Actually, your object is declared global.

```
p=test()
p.var="good bye"
p.arr = []
p.num = 5
```

In the above snippet, the `p` object is declared outside of the scope of the methods, which allows all of them to access it. Methods are also declared outside of the `test` class scope. There is nothing actually prevents them from accessing it. If you want debug for better understanding, move the `p` object inside one of the methods--like:

```
def output_before():
   p=test()
   p.var="good bye"
   p.arr = []
   p.num = 5
   print "before change: object text " ,p.var
   print "before change: object number ", p.num
   print "before change: basic text " ,text
   print "before change: basic num ", num
```

And re-run your code, that would produce:

```
before change: object text  good bye
before change: object number  5
before change: basic text  hi there
before change: basic num  1
```

And then the following error:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "t.py", line 35, in 
>       change()   File "t.py", line 29, in change
>       p.num=10 NameError: **global name 'p' is not defined**

However, if you want to access objects from inside modules or methods, you can use the keyword `global`, and as the doc proposes:

> This is because when you make an assignment to a variable in a scope, that variable becomes local to that scope and shadows any similarly named variable in the outer scope. Since the last statement in foo assigns a new value to x, the compiler recognizes it as a local variable. Consequently when the earlier print x attempts to print the uninitialized local variable and an error results, **you can access the outer scope variable by declaring it global**

[Read More](https://docs.python.org/2/faq/programming.html#what-are-the-rules-for-local-and-global-variables-in-python)

Comment: So both the object p and the variables text and num are declared outside. Why my object p is accessed without the global keyword, but the variables have to have it ?

Comment: Your variables can be accessed too.

Comment: Debug by printing the `text` or `num` variables inside any of your methods.

Answer (score 0):

This is just like any other variable in Python. The function first checks within the local namespace for the variable. Since the object is not defined inside the function, it checks the outer namespace which is the global namespace, where you have actually defined it.

For the variable num/text, you are using `num = 5` in `change()`. This creates a local variable called `num` and assigns 5 to that. It does not change the global variable. If you want to change it globaly then you can use global keyword:

```
def change():
    global text,num
    num = 5  #Global num is changed
```

Answer (score 0):

Just think of your object p as any other primitive type. The rules are same for both.

Since you declare your object outside the functions, the scope of this object is not limited. On the other hand, if you declare it on of your functions, then you cannot access your object outside these functions as the scope of this object is now limited to this function alone. (Ofcourse you can explicitely make this global. But that is probably out of scope at the moment for this question)

```
class test():
    pass

text="hi there"
num=1

def output_before():
    #p is now local
    p=test()
    p.var="good bye"
    p.arr = []
    p.num = 5
    print("before change: object text " ,p.var)
    print("before change: object number ", p.num)
    print("before change: basic text " ,text)
    print("before change: basic num ", num)
    print(b)

def output_after():
    print("after change: object text " ,p.var) #should fail because p is not known
    print("after change: object number ", p.num)
    print("after change: basic text " ,text)
    print("after change: basic num ", num)



def change():
    text = "whats up"
    num=5
    p.num=10
    p.var="good night"
    p.arr.append ("sleep well")


output_before()
change()
output_after()
```

The above code shall fail because p is not unknown in change() and output_after().